# Defaulting List to Null in Linq

Tags: c#, list, linq

First of all forgive me if I don't get the terminology right. I have a class called A, which contains methods that gets and returns different values. One of the methods, called B, gets and returns a list of ClassB which value can be null. Therefore I'm initializing ClassB as a blank list like below:

```
public class A
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public List<ClassB> B { get; set; } = new List<ClassB>();
```

}

```
public class B
{
    public int BTypeId { get; set; }      
}
```

Then I have a method C outside of class A and B, that calls class A like below.

```
public void create (A a)
{
var request 1 = B.getSomething();
var request2 = a.request1.Select(s => s.BTypeId);
}
```

However I got an error when trying to assign value for request2:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in mscorlib.dll
```

I think it doesn't like it when I throw an empty list. The code will work fine if the B List is not empty.
My question is how to assign value to request2 so that it will accept an empty list?

Comment: You need to change your code so that the list is not null.

Comment: There is not enough information here at present. i mean i cant reproduce anything and its unclear what you are asking. Please consider adding the appropriate information to this question so its reproducible

Comment: Unfortunately the lists passed will be empty.. I need to make a change to this code to accept empty lists instead.

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code and make sure post contains reasonable amount of information to reproduce the problem. I.e. as it stands now `A` does not have `request1` - so what `a.request1.Select(s => s.BTypeId);` does or why it fails is impossible to say.

Comment: There is no class called `ClassB` and there is no property called `request1` in your code. So it's not cleat what issue you are facing why. Please share a code which can be built and run to reproduce the issue.